# SQL trigger on delete

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a small question. I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE park(parkcode CHAR(5), name CHAR(15));

CREATE TABLE ticket(date_purchase_ticket TIMESTAMP, parkcode CHAR(5));
```

What I am trying to do is to create a trigger that when I want to delete a row from table `park`, the trigger first looks to see if there were any purchases after a certain date. And only if there were no purchases after a certain date then you can delete that row from the table `park`.

Comment: What database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, and not a database product. Stuff like this is very vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: Please post your trigger code and describe the problem you're having with it.

Comment: I am so sorry i totally forgot to include the database system. its mysql

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about making a procedure that you can call when you want to delete a row from `park`.

Something along the lines of:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteIfNoPurchases (IN code CHAR(5),
                                      IN date TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT MAX(date_purchase_ticket)
         FROM ticket
         WHERE parkcode = code) < date THEN
        DELETE FROM park WHERE parkcode = code; 
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can call it with the code you want to delete and the timestamp you want to test against.

Answer (score 0):

You can not prevent deleting a row with trigger.